# Google Drive API Multipart upload 502 error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-drive-realtime-api

I have PHP code which inserts files into Google Drive.  Most of the time it works fine. However I've noticed lately that it will randomly return a 502 error as follows:

```
  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>
...
  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I believe is a temporary error from Google.
It turns out that the file was actually created on Google Drive, so when I retry the request, I end up with a duplicate file.

As it's returned an error instead of a Files resource, how do I get the ID for the new file from Google?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters), where your search a file by name. You can also set it to [Resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable), it is more reliable when uploading large files. It will also lower your chances of getting a duplicate file (see [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#best-practices), to be aware of some best practices related to error handling). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot, I forgot about resumable upload!
My challenge is I'm transferring files from one cloud to another so I don't have a "filepath" to reference and read chunks from.  I am getting the file contents and then writing it straight to Google Drive.  Which works ok for small files (with the odd exception of 502 sporadically).

To perform resumeable upload, would I need to write the file contents first to some storage and then chunk it down to Google Drive?